# Fastest way to know if a column has a constant value in a PySpark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I want to assert if the values of a PySpark DataFrame column are the same across all rows. For example, having the next DataFrame

```
+----------+----------+
|    A     |    B     |
+----------+----------+
|       2.0|       0.0|
|       0.0|       0.0|
|       1.0|       0.0|
|       1.0|       0.0|
|       0.0|       0.0|
|       1.0|       0.0|
|       0.0|       0.0|
+----------+----------+
```

the column "A" is not constant and "B" is.

I have tried two methods:

1- Check the stddev = 0:

```
df.select(stddev(col('B'))).collect()
```

2- Get distinct values:

```
df.select("B").distinct().collect()
```

The first method takes 16min to finish and the second one 12min, but it's only one execution, so I'm not sure about significance.

What is the best way to check it in PySpark?

Comment: Maybe something like [`countDistinct`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#countDistinct-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-), where the count is 1 for 'constant' values and bigger otherwise?

Comment: For speed reasons, maybe `approx_count_distinct` could work too, but I guess it might depend on your application case.

Comment: do you know value itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stdev` is quite complicated operation, `distinct` too. 
If your task is to check if all values in specific column equals to some specific variable, I’d try to do smth like.

`df.filter(col('B') != your_value).count() == 0`

It might be the case that you don’t know value of that column. But it’s easy to resolve, just by retrieving head(any) value and comparing against it:

`your_value = df.select('B').first()[0]`

Comment: Thanks, it seems much faster. I do not know the value, but the trick of comparing with the first one seems very good to me.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with vvg's approach.

#### Nan Bug:

If `your_value` is `nan` the comparison results in `nan` which gets turned into `false` by `filter` leading to columns with first value of `nan` being considered constant.

#### Inefficiency:

Counting and checking if it is zero seems a very inefficient way to do `any`. Consider calling limit, take or head on your df before counting.

#### In Total:

```
first_value = df.select('B').filter(~F.col('B').isNull()).first()[0]
df.filter(col('B') != first_value).limit(1).count() == 0
```