# Stop pyspark aggregation if condition triggers

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say I want to check if a pyspark dataframe has any constant column. Let's work with the dataframe from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52113821/fastest-way-to-know-if-a-column-has-a-constant-value-in-a-pyspark-dataframe):

```
+----------+----------+
|    A     |    B     |
+----------+----------+
|       2.0|       0.0|
|       0.0|       0.0|
|       1.0|       0.0|
|       1.0|       0.0|
|       0.0|       0.0|
|       1.0|       0.0|
|       0.0|       0.0|
+----------+----------+
```

Isn't it a way of generate:

```
+----------+----------+
|    A     |    B     |
+----------+----------+
|     False|      True|
+----------+----------+
```

Without having to aggregate/filter the whole A column as proposed in this question solution? (let's say, if I dectect two rows aren't equal during aggregation, stop the operation and return False), thus, saving time? Does spark do it internally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no short circuit feature allowing this. So, no.

Comment: Isn't it inefficient? Do you know if there is there a reason behind this?

Comment: Hard to build such stuff. What say if adjacent data is in next partition, for example. Even with checking all columns in a row you need to work in particular way.

Comment: I was thinking about shomething like [rdd.aggregate](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.aggregate.html) with an exit condition for both seqOp and combOp

Comment: Its an rdd implementation, not sure how that would work. Let us know.